# Simplest custom button: It shows in admin panel for text format, but not in the editor

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

I have followed [this tutorial](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Tutorials/Timestamp_Plugin) to make simple custom button for CKEditor.
I managed to get it visible in Drupal admin panel and I added my button to admin/config/content/formats/manage/full_html.

[image]

When I then edit any node with CKEditor with the appropriate text format (full HTML), I don't see my button.

[image]

What am I missing?

Here is the content of the plugin.js file, located in /libraries/blockbutton.

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'blockbutton',
{
    init: function( editor )
    {
        editor.addCommand( 'insertTimestamp',
            {
                exec : function( editor )
                {    
                    var timestamp = new Date();
                    editor.insertHtml( 'The current date and time is: <em>' + timestamp.toString() + '</em>' );
                }
            });
        editor.ui.addButton( 'Timestamp',
        {
            label: 'Insert Timestamp',
            command: 'insertTimestamp',
            icon: this.path + 'icons/bgcolor.png'
        } );
    }
} );
```

This is a simple module based on the Color button module.

```
class BlockButton extends CKEditorPluginBase implements CKEditorPluginConfigurableInterface {

  public function getDependencies(Editor $editor) {
    return ['panelbutton'];
  }

  public function getFile() {
    return 'libraries/blockbutton/plugin.js';
  }

  public function getConfig(Editor $editor) {
    $settings = $editor->getSettings();
    $config = [];
    return $config;
  }

  public function getButtons() {
    return [
      'insertTimestamp' => array(
        'label' => $this->t('insertTimestamp'),
        'image' => 'libraries/blockbutton/icons/textcolor.png',
      )
    ];
  }

  public function settingsForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, Editor $editor) {
    $settings = $editor->getSettings();
    return $form;
  }

  public function validateInput(array $element, FormStateInterface $form_state) {}
}
```

Drupal log is clear.

Comment: I'm confused, was this copy pasted from another plugin ? Why is it called block button? I'm fairly certain the button name needs to match

Comment: @Kevin - JS is based on tutorial I've mentioned at the begining (http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Tutorials/Timestamp_Plugin). And the PHP/drupal plugin part is based on colorbutton plugin (renamed to blockbutton and cleared of extra code).

Comment: @Kevin can you elaborate on "I'm fairly certain the button name needs to match"? I use `insertTimestamp` in JS for `command` inside `addButton` and I use exact same string for `getButtons()` in PHP (and in `addCommand` in JS). Which string should match which? Maybe I'm missing something. Note that the buttons shows up in admin panel and it's invisible only in node edit.

Comment: AFAIK you need to document the required HTML tags and so on you need, and it only shows up if those are allowed in the chosen text format. Might be related to that

Comment: That is also true